# React calculations in render vs in lifecycle methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand something about react and would like to get thoughts on the better way to do it.

Basically, I want to do some transformations/calculations on incoming props. I have limited event based state changes currently, but that may change in the future. Basically, is it better to do these calculations in render, or in componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps and set state?

in render example:

```
render() {
  var url = this.getUrl() // get url transforms some props into a valid url
  var something = this.getSomething() // etc etc

  return <a href={url}>{something}</a>
}
```

outside of render:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this._checkAndSetUrl(this.getUrl(this.props.data));
},
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const currentGivenUrl = this._getUrl(this.props.data)
  const nextGivenUrl = this._getUrl(nextProps.data)

  if (currentGivenUrl !== nextGivenUrl) {
    this._checkAndSetUrl(nextGivenUrl);
  }
},
_checkAndSetUrl(url) {
  // check validity and do some stuff to url
  url = "new url" 
  something = this.getSomething()

  this.setState({url: url, something: something})
}
```

My thinking is the second way is better because you don't do the calculations on every render, only when things are changed. What's the accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for simplicity and readability you should keep them in render, and implement `shouldComponentUpdate`:

```
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  // TODO: return whether or not current chat thread is
  // different to former one. this.props refers to the 'old' props.
}
```

If you return false from `shouldComponentUpdate`, render will not be called again. If `this.props.data === nextProps.data` you can probably return false.

It avoids you keeping around unnecessary state, and is readable. If you want to make the checks more granular you can split up your `url` and `something` into different components, with their own `shouldComponentUpdate`.

For more information, see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html

Comment: Yes it is generally recommended that you do not put computed data into state and instead recompute it in render.  See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state

Comment: Also, it is better to do in `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle specific things only: stuff where you need current `this.props` as well as next props, or stuff where you need to update state based on new props.